# Netty send message to Server without for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, client, netty, server

I was using the following code to send messages from the Client to the Server:

Client class:

```
public class Client {

  String host = "localhost";
  int port = 14930;
  private final ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();

  public Client(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
  }

  public void run() throws Exception {

    try {
      workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
      Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
      b.group(workerGroup);
      b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
      b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
      b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
          public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
          ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
          pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
          pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
          pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());
          pipeline.addLast(clientHandler);
        }
      }
      );

      ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync();

      f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
    finally {
      workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
  }
  public void writeMessage(String msg) {
    clientHandler.sendMessage(msg);
  }
}
```

Handler class:

```
public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
  ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

  public void sendMessage(String msgToSend) {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msgToSend, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
  }

  @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
  }

  @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String msg) throws Exception {
  }

  void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

I am creating the Client like this:

```
Client client;
client = new Client(ipAddress, serverPort);
client.run();
client.writeMessage("random_text");
```

The Server:

```
public final class ChatServer {

  public ChatServer(int PORT) throws Exception {

    bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
      ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
      b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
          .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
            .childHandler(new ChatServerInitializer());

      b.bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } 
    finally {
      bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
      workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
  }
}
```

ServerHandler:

```
public class ChatServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

  public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Channel incoming = ctx.channel();
    channels.add(ctx.channel());
  }

  public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Channel incoming = ctx.channel();
    channels.remove(ctx.channel());
  } 

  @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
  }

  @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
    println(msg);
  }
}
```

Method to send Message from Server to Client:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
  if (message != "" && message != null) {
    for (Channel c : channels) {
      c.writeAndFlush(message + "\r\n");
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the Server does not get any Messages. I tried some debug steps, the Server adds the Client to its channels, and channelActive gets executed successfully on the Client side.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of polling the variable the whole time you should try to transfer the communication to the handler (either your `ChatClientInitializer` or an extra handler that you add last). Give this handler a method that you call when a new message was entered. The handler then writes to the channel.

Maybe this example helps:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {

    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 9128;
    private final ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private ExecutorService executor = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.startClient();
        client.writeMessage("random_text");
        //client.stopClient();  //call this at some point to shutdown the client
    }

    public synchronized void startClient() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            executor.execute(this);
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean stopClient() {
        boolean bReturn = true;
        if (isRunning) {
            if (executor != null) {
                executor.shutdown();
                try {
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    if (executor.awaitTermination(calcTime(10, 0.66667), TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        if (!executor.awaitTermination(calcTime(10, 0.33334), TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                            bReturn = false;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } finally {
                    executor = null;
                }
            }
            isRunning = false;
        }
        return bReturn;
    }

    private long calcTime(int nTime, double dValue) {
        return (long) ((double) nTime * dValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(workerGroup);
            b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline(); 
                    pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
                    pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
                    pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());
                    pipeline.addLast(clientHandler);
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync();

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // do nothing
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public void writeMessage(String msg) {
        clientHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

A very basic ClientHandler:

```
public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    public void sendMessage(String msgToSend) {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ChannelFuture cf = ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msgToSend, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            ctx.flush();
            if (!cf.isSuccess()) {
                System.out.println("Send failed: " + cf.cause());
            }
        } else {
            //ctx not initialized yet. you were too fast. do something here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String msg) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: But I experienced the Client shuting down when there is no for loop and it directly goes to the shutdown code. On the other side, how would the clientHandler look like?

Comment: you are most probably closing the connection on the serverside then. in my code the client only shuts down if the connection gets closed. I'll edit the answer with a ClientHandler example.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that and report back as soon as I get home!

Comment: I have a bit of a problem. How would I call the `sendMessage` method? I get a cannot make a static reference error when calling it like `ChatClientHandler.sendMessage();`

Comment: instantiate your handler like I did in line 5 of my code: `private final ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();`. Then you can call `clientHandler.sendMessage(msg);`

Comment: Oh it seems I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I seem to be getting a nullpointerexception when calling writeMessage?

Comment: I solved the problem with the NPE, but now the Server does not get any message. U edited the code in the question.

Comment: Now I get a NPE when calling `ctx.writeAndFlush`

Comment: So I fixed also that problem but the server still doesn`t get anything.

Comment: I edited my answer again. Your client should be a thread. the main method contains an example of how to call it but calling the `writeMessage()` so soon after the starting will result in the channel context not being initialized yet.

Comment: Yes, I already fixed this problem and ctx is no longer null when I send something, but the server does not get any message, it does not matter when I send it, even if I wait a minute before sending, server doesn't ger anything, but the method to send the message gets executed successfully.

Comment: That could have various reasons. take a look at the modified `sendMessage()` method of my `ClientHandler`. If the client encounters a problem it should print it. If the client shows a success then the server is not handling this type of message.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and report back

Comment: So sending Messages to the Server now works, but now the Client doesn't get any messages sent from the server

Comment: Updated the Question to include Server Code

Comment: the server handler doesn't send any message.

Comment: I created a method to send messages from the server which worked fine till I changed the client. Updated the question to include the method

Comment: And how can I fix that?

Comment: you have a `channelRead0()` method in your client handler. do something there. maybe just print out the message as it does in your server handler

Comment: I have it printing the message on the Client side too, but it does not print anything. Also I noticed it sometimes prints "Send failed: null" even though the Server gets the message just fine.

Comment: please create a new question out of this.

Comment: Maybe I would ask "getContext" to a handler and actually send the message in the Client. What do you think?

Comment: @sebadagostino did you get this working? care to share a working example here